Issues Hosting Flutter Web App - Missing Files and 404 Errors
I am trying to host a Flutter web application on Vercel. While accessing the hosted app, I encounter the following errors:

GET https://demo-services-iota.vercel.app/trenTech/flutter_bootstrap.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
GET https://demo-services-iota.vercel.app/trenTech/manifest.json 404 (Not Found)
manifest.json: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error.

It seems like the flutter_bootstrap.js and manifest.json files are either missing or incorrectly referenced.
Observations:

The hosted app URL attempts to find files under the /trenTech/ path, but this folder structure does exist in the build output.
The app works correctly in a local environment when served using a simple HTTP server & while working when deployed in the Apache server.

Questions:

Does Vercel require specific configurations for hosting Flutter web apps (e.g., adjustments to vercel.json or routing)?
(I HAVE DEPLOYED DIRECTLY FROM THE GITHUB REPOSITORY)
How can I ensure that all required files are properly referenced and served?
Is there a way to debug or validate file paths during deployment?

Steps Taken So Far:

Built the Flutter app for the web using flutter build web --output-dir=build/trenTech --base-href=/trenTech/ --release.
Deployed the build/trenTech folder to Vercel using from the vercel website directly.
Verified that the files exist locally in the build/trenTech directory.




Please add a [mre].
